# Independence of distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, random-matrices

Let there be a random matrix defined as
$\mathbf{H}_1 = X + \boldsymbol\nu$, where, $X$ is deterministic and $\boldsymbol\nu$ is Gaussian white noise. Now let there be another random matrix defined as $\mathbf{H}_2 = Y + \boldsymbol\nu$, where $Y$ is deterministic. Here $X$ and $Y$ are different matrices, but they are perturbed by the same noise, $\boldsymbol\nu$. Can I say that the distributions of $\mathbf{H}_1$ and $\mathbf{H}_2$ are independent of each other. i.e. is $p\left(\mathbf{H}_1\mathbf{H}_2\right)=p\left(\mathbf{H}_1\right)p\left(\mathbf{H}_2\right)$?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot. As $H_2 = H_1 - (Y - X)$, $H_2$ is the difference of $H_1$ and something deterministic, that is, given $H_1$, we know $H_2$, so $H_1$ and $H_2$ are dependent.

Comment: I am not sure whether we can write $\mathbf{H}_2=\mathbf{H}_1-\left(\mathbf{Y}-\mathbf{X}\right)$. We can, at most write, E$\left[\mathbf{H}_2\right]=E\left[\mathbf{H}_1\right]-\left(\mathbf{Y}-\mathbf{X}\right)$. Where E[] is expectation operator.

Comment: Why? As $H_1 = X + \nu$, and $H_2 = Y + \nu$, we have $H_1 - H_2 = X - Y$?

Comment: $\boldsymbol\nu$ is not deterministic. It is a Gaussian white noise. It is random. So, in other words, $\mathbf{H}_1 = \mathbf{X}+\boldsymbol\nu_1$ and $\mathbf{H}_2 = \mathbf{Y}+\boldsymbol\nu_2$. Where, $\boldsymbol\nu_1$ and $\boldsymbol\nu_2$ have same statistical properties.

Comment: Then you should write it as that in your question. If your $\nu_i$ are different, independent, but identically distributed random variables, then of course, $H_1$ and $H_2$ are also independent. But if $\nu$, as you write is in both $H_i$ **the same noise**, it does not make any difference that it is random.

Comment: @user146290: martini is correct. If you are having a hard time grasping the equality of random variables, note that a random variable is actually a function from a probability space to the real line (measure theoretic definition). Imagine two functions $f$ & $g$, with $f(x)=x^2, g(x)=x^2, x \in R$. Isn't f = g? Similarly, it is entirely possible to have two random variables $X$ and $Y$ with $X(\omega)=Y(\omega)$ for all $\omega$, in which case we have $X=Y$.